# Can't start mongodb server using 'sudo service mongod start'

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set up a dummy mongodb server on my local device so I can play around with it and make mistakes so that I can feel confident editing the actual server. I use the following code to start the mongodb server:

```
 sudo service mongod start
```

However executing `sudo service mongod status` outputs the following:

```
   ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-08-29 15:46:44 ACST; 754ms ago
         Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
      Process: 14604 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=62)
     Main PID: 14604 (code=exited, status=62)
          CPU: 1.889s

    Aug 29 15:46:42 david-Aspire-A515-51G systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    Aug 29 15:46:42 david-Aspire-A515-51G mongod[14604]: 2018-08-29T15:46:42.435+0930 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
    Aug 29 15:46:44 david-Aspire-A515-51G systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=62/n/a
    Aug 29 15:46:44 david-Aspire-A515-51G systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Aug 29 15:46:44 david-Aspire-A515-51G systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Tried adding `sudo service mongod start --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'` to no avail.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Running following code in terminal fixed my issue for error 62:

```
mv /var/lib/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb_backup
mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
chmod 700 /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:daemon /var/lib/mongodb
systemctl restart mongodb
```